# Cannot open NetCDF file

Tags: netcdf

I produced a NetCDF file by combining two others using NCO (specifically `ncbo` command). I cannot open the output with QGIS though. Indeed, I get the following error msg:
`"Download with "Protocol" source failed, do you want to try the "File" source type?"`.

Whatever answer I give the file is not opened.

I manage to get info about the file using gdalinfo. Below are the details:

```
Warning 1: Recode from UTF-8 to CP_ACP failed with the error: "Invalid argument".
Warning 1: No UNIDATA NC_GLOBAL:Conventions attribute
Driver: HDF5/Hierarchical Data Format Release 5
Files: c_gls_output.nc
Size is 512, 512
Metadata:
  history=Wed Apr 14 16:15:16 2021: ncbo --op_typ=divide a.nc b.nc c_gls_output.nc
  lat_CLASS=DIMENSION_SCALE
  lat_NAME=lat
  lat__FillValue=nan
  lat__Netcdf4Dimid=0
  lon_CLASS=DIMENSION_SCALE
  lon_NAME=lon
  lon__FillValue=nan
  lon__Netcdf4Dimid=1
  NCO=4.7.2
  _NCProperties=version=1|netcdflibversion=4.6.0|hdf5libversion=1.10.0
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0,  512.0)
Upper Right (  512.0,    0.0)
Lower Right (  512.0,  512.0)
Center      (  256.0,  256.0)
```

Is there any workaround, may be changing some of the metadata, in order to be able to open the file?

Comment: What is the result from ncdump -h c_gls_output.nc

Comment: here is the output I get `{
dimensions:
        lat = 8961 ;
        lon = 10081 ;
variables:
        double lat(lat) ;
                lat:_FillValue = NaN ;
        double lon(lon) ;
                lon:_FillValue = NaN ;

// global attributes:
                :history = "Wed Apr 14 16:15:16 2021: ncbo --op_typ=divide a.nc b.nc c_gls_output.nc\nWed Apr 14 15:59:35 2021: ncdiff NDVI_20190411.nc NDVI-LTS_min.nc a.nc" ;
                :NCO = "4.7.2" ;
}
`